# video en bucle visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

Hola estoy realizando un proyecto en visual studio y quiero incrustar un video y que este se reproduzca en una y otra vez.

He agredado un componente WindowsMedia Player y este es el codigo que lo controla.

```
 axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = Application.StartupPath + "/video.mp4";
 axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();
```

Pero no se como hacer que se reproduzca en bucle.

Comment: Visual Studio no es un lenguaje de programación. ¿Es C#?

Answer (score 0):

Me autorespondo por si a alguien le puede servir.

El codigo a quedado asi:

```
 axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = Application.StartupPath + "/video.mp4";
 axWindowsMediaPlayer1.settings.setMode("loop", true);
 axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();
```